# Python, hstack column numpy arrays (column vectors) of different types

Tags: python, numpy

I currently have a numpy multi-dimensional array (of type float) and a numpy column array (of type int).  I want to combine the two into a mutli-dimensional numpy array.

```
import numpy

>> dates.shape
(1251,)
>> data.shape
(1251,10)
>> test = numpy.hstack((dates, data))
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

To show that the types of the arrays are different:

```
>> type(dates[0])
<type 'numpy.int64'>
>> type(data[0,0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: I'm showing numpy.dstack as stacking along the 3rd axis.  I want to take a 1251, 10 (in this case) and turn it into a 1251, 11, are you suggesting that i would use dstack for that?

Comment: Ah ok sorry thought you wanted a 1251,1251,10

Comment: Short of using an object array, you can't do this. Numpy arrays can, by definition, only contain a single type. So the only alternative is to cast the integer array to floating point, then stack them.

Comment: I believe a 1-D numpy array is treated as a **row** vector, not a column vector.  I recall tripping over this recently as my intuition is that 1-D arrays should be column vectors :)  Have you tried `dates.shape = (1251,1)`?

Comment: Thanks, that actually allows me to changes things more cleanly when I pre-allocate.  I had:
    m,n = data.shape
    dates = numpy.empty(shape = temp.shape)
now I can just make it
    dates = numpy.empty(shape = (m,1)) (because the number of dates must equal the number of rows of the date vector) and everything works fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

np.column_stack((dates, data))
```

The types are cast automatically to the most precise, so your int array will be converted to float.

Comment: Thanks so much Griffith, this certainly did the trick, much appreciated, I was hoping to not have to cast the floats to get back to ordinals, but it'll work just fine, thanks again!

Comment: If you like my answer give me a vote and check it as the correct one ;)

Answer (score 1):

The types don't matter, you should reshape dates to be (1251, 1) before using hstack.

Ps. The ints will be cast to float.

Answer (score 0):

`test = numpy.hstack((dates[:,numpy.newaxis], data))`